# rails select_tag with option value as hash/json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb

I have a `select_tag` and want that the value of the `option` is like a json format so I can save it as `jsonb`.

I build an helper for the select:
`colors.map {|c| [ c['color-name'], {c['color-name'] => c['color-code']} ] }`

but the option in the select_tag is rendered:

`<option red="#ff0000" value="red">red</option>` instead of: `<option  value="{"red:"ff00000"}">red</option>`

Comment: The reason the hash is being assigned as attributes is that the method treats the last argument as options if its a hash. While you could manually call `.to_json` on that hash to get a string and then manually parse out the JSON string from the parameters before assigning it to the model the whole thing stinks to the high heavens. You can pass hashes and arrays in formdata anyways by just naming the inputs correctly like for example `'colors[red]=ff00000&colors[blue]=0000FF'` which gives `{"colors"=>{"red"=>"ff00000", "blue"=>"0000FF"}} `.

Comment: It should also be noted that `<option  value="{"red:"ff00000"}" ...` is invalid HTML and will break the page. You would have to escape the quotes.